# i am working on c# for desktop application. how can i redirect my page with login page from oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle, authentication

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string oradb = "Data Source=pdb1;User ID=test1;Password=test1;Unicode=True";
    try
    {
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(oradb);
        con.Open();
        //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Connected to Oracle" + con.ServerVersion);
        //string userid = user.Text;
        OracleParameter p_userid = new OracleParameter();
        p_userid.ParameterName = "p_user_id";
        p_userid.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;

        OracleParameter count = new OracleParameter();
        p_userid.ParameterName = "v_count";
        p_userid.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;

        OracleParameter p_res = new OracleParameter();
        p_userid.ParameterName = "p_res";
        p_userid.OracleType = OracleType.VarChar;

        OracleParameter[] oraparms = new OracleParameter[] {p_userid,count,p_res };

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("prc_login",con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(oraparms);

        object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();


        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently your question just consists of a title and code. Please add significantly more explanation of what you're trying to do, and the problems you're facing doing it. Given that you're writing a desktop application, what does "redirect my page" even mean?

Comment: Desktop applications do not have redirecting feature. You close one form and open another.